# Dynamically add tabs content in mobile page

Tags: jquery-mobile

I use $('#tab-content').load('/embed_tab.html'); to load below page, the output is in bullet point instead of tabs? This is the page I load when I click something on parent page. How can I solve the problem.

Script

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
```

is loaded from the head.

```
    <div data-role="tabs" id="detail-tabs">
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#sellpoint" data-ajax="false" class="ui-tab-left ui-btn-active">Selling Point</a></li>
          <li><a href="#terms" data-ajax="false" class="ui-tab-right">Terms of Use</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <div id="sellpoint" class="ui-body-d ui-content">
        <h1>Selling Point</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="terms">
        <h1>Terms of Use</h1>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are also loading the jQM javascript as well as the css.

After the $('#tab-content').load('/embed_tab.html'); is finished, you have to initialize the tabs widget to cause it to be enhanced. So once the load is complete, try calling something like:

```
$('#tab-content').enhanceWithin();
```

or

```
$('#tab-content [data-role="tabs"]').tabs();
```

**EDIT:** to call these after the load is complete, use the complete callback function of the load method:

```
$('#tab-content').load('/embed_tab.html', function() {
  $('#tab-content').enhanceWithin();
});
```

API DOC: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: both not work, still showing tabs in bullet point instead of tabs.

Comment: are you calling `enhanceWithin()` on the `parent` you are appending your HTML to?

Comment: @frequent, yes, enhanceWithin() is called on the parent element to enhance all children.

Comment: @user3059850, did you use the complete callback of the load method? Using this callback allows the method to finish inserting the new HTML before running the script. See my updated response.

Comment: How can I do the complete callback? I made a sample on http://www.852ebiz.com/pub/ems2/

Comment: Thanks user3059850, it works now using callback after the load. By the way, how do I know I need to call enhanceWithin() to make it works? Any guideline I have to follow ?

Comment: @user3059850, anytime you add widgets dynamically after the page is already created, jQM does not automatically initialize and enhance, so you need to do it in script.

Comment: Thanks ezanker, sorry I misunderstand user3059850 is you. As you said, can I say we need to call enhanceWithIn() for every dynamically widgets build if the widgets include html elements and then jQuery Mobile will rebuilt all the appearance?

Comment: @user3059850, you either call enhanceWithin() or the individual widget initializer. so for tabs you would call .tabs(), for a radio button, .checkboxradio(), etc. See the widget docs here: http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/widgets/